# No login screen after leaving the computer for two hours

Tags: password

Usually when I leave the computer for just few minutes, it logs off automatically and asks me for the password when I come back. But today I left the house for two hours while leaving the computer running, and when I came back and turned the monitor back on, the desktop was already there without asking for the password. Is it normal?

Comment: Next time you leave the house lock the screen before you leave. If you are using 18.04 check that screen lock is set to On in System Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock.

Answer (score 0):

To lock the screen automatically, you must configure the privacy settings in your Ubuntu:

- Configure the [automatic lock](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/privacy-screen-lock.html) in: `System Settings > Privacy > Screen Lock`.

You can find an icon for the `System Settings` in the top bar of your desktop. There are some screenshots that may help you in the [websiteforstudents site](https://websiteforstudents.com/disable-ubuntu-17-10-lock-screen/).

---

If you plan to leave your computer for a while, you can also lock the screen manually:

- You can press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key combination (<kbd>Super</kbd> is usually the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key).
- or use a command like: `gnome-screensaver-command --lock`